# Running an executable binary made w/ JET Excelsior in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm starting out with Docker, trying to add my application into it, to run. The application is Java-based compiled using Jet Excelsior.

I use the following simple docker file for building.

```
#Dockerfile

FROM alpine:latest
COPY ["/", "/sandbox"]
WORKDIR /sandbox
ENTRYPOINT ["myapp"]
CMD ["-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal","-XX:+PrintGCDetails"]
```

I build with the standard `docker build -t sandbox .`

I confirm that the folder structure and all files are properly transferred. I do this by `docker run sandbox ls *`. But when I do docker run sandbox I get the error:

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"myapp\": executable file not found in $PATH"

I've tried not using the exec form i.e ENTRYPOINT / CMD myapp; even ENTRYPOINT / CMD ./myapp, to which I get:

> /bin/sh: myapp: not found

Can anyone help?

Comment: I just want to add that I also went the route of using a java-ready base image, and used my app in its jar form w/ foldered resources and dependencies. This executes and runs well. I still would prefer using my app in its binary form. however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently didn't look hard enough, before posting this question. It turns out there is a [specific solution](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/kb/39/howto-containerize-a-natively-compiled-java-application-using-docker) to this question in JET Excelsior's knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the file and not the entire folder. If that doesnt work try CMD["myapp","arg1",...] without entrypoint.

Update: I think you might not have copied the file over. You could run ls inside the container to see how the file system in the container looks. You copy / this is the root directory of your file system. Did you maybe want to copy . (current directory)?

Comment: I can confirm everything was copied over. I do RUN ls -la /sandbox/* to see the contents during the build, and I see it's all there. I also do it post build, just in case.

Comment: You are copying the root directory of your machine. This means you copy over everything on your machine. I think that is a bad idea. Only copy the files you actually need.

Comment: hmm, but the only files that get copied are what's in the folder where I put all the items for the application. But yes, I also did (and switched back to) using COPY [".", "/sandbox"]

Comment: you didn't specify anywhere to use java to run the binary

Comment: sorry for the confusion. As stated on the question, the app is compiled as a native binary using Jet Excelsior, which bundles a custom JRE. When the application is invoked, there is no need to do "java -args". My comment on the question was for when I did not use the JET compiled app, and just created a Docker image using the executable jar + resources.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to find a specific solution in their knowledgebase, which I'll post as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is "myapp" file exist in WORKDIR directory (WORKDIR/myapp) ? 
Now you copy all local root directory (/) to /sandbox container dir.

```
COPY ["/", "/sandbox"]
```

if you need/want to copy root directory to container you need use full path of the the "myapp", example:

```
ENTRYPOINT /full/path/in/container/to/myapp
```

Or just update the PATH:

```
ENV PATH="/full/path/in/container/to/:${PATH}"
```

But maybe best decision would be change COPY command to:

```
COPY [".", "/sandbox"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Alisher. I'll try your recommendations for entry point and env path. I did try copy [".", "/sandbox"] before, and it was the same as copy ["/", "/sandbox"]

Comment: Tried those 2 out, still getting standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"